# Addition of two numbers is exponential value

Tags: php

When I add two integers in php and echo the result, the printed result will be in exponetial format, e.g.
`7.8274928374928E+136`.

Is there a solution to print the result in non-exponential expression (without a decimal mark), like this:

`78274928374928...`

```
<?php
$a=7867869786987263478632476347823647823648723648723648723648726;
$b=78274928374928374982374982749823749287349827492847298472983284723984729837429837429837498274829749827498274893279847984732984732984732984;
$c=$a+$b;
echo $c;

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: where is output? where is code?

Comment: [Click here before you post your next question.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Comment: use `sprintf` or `number_format` instead of echo

Comment: I dont want to use any php inbuilt functions like number_format

Comment: __Why__ don't you want to use any built in function like number_format()? PHP is sensible, it reverts to displaying numbers in scientific format when they exceed a certain threshold because most developers __don't__ want 140 digits displayed... but allow you to use functions like sprint() or number_format() to change this behaviour.... I suppose you don't want to use bc_math or gmp to do the maths either

Comment: I can't answer you since the question is on hold. Your numbers are so big that you run into [integer overflow](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow). As a result all your numbers will be converted to float. In addition, you lose precision. You could solve the problem if you change your numbers to be always smaller than 2^31-1

Comment: @MyPasswordIsLasercats thanks for your reply.
I am helpless with input part,this is the requirement i have.

Comment: But does that requirement prevent you from using extensions like [bc_math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [gmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php)?

Comment: If you can neither change the input nor use extensions like BC Math, you have to write your own kind of BigInteger class. If even this is not allowed/possible then the answers to your question is: "No, it is not possible"

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker ill check if i can go with your suggestion or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your numbers are so big that you run into [integer overflow](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow). As a result all your numbers will be converted to float. In addition, you lose precision. You could solve the problem if you change your numbers to be always smaller than 2^31-1.

If you really need those big numbers (e.g. for cryptography) you should rely on external functions like [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) (Mark Baker also mentioned [GNU Multiple Precision](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) what I didn't know yet :)

If external functions are not allowed, too, you have to write your own classes and define all mathematical operations on it... but this might be a big deal for what you try to achieve.

When you don't want or are not allowed to write you own BigInteger-class, the answer to your question is probably: "No, it is not possible under these requirements."